# How to make twin toddlers stop biting each other without physical punishment?

Tags: toddler, discipline, twins, biting

How can I stop my almost 2-year-old twins from biting each other? I've tried almost everything and nothing works, so I'm looking for some other suggestions. They are biting to the point of bruises. It's just getting worse as they've gotten older.

Comment: This question could do with some more body. What have you tried so far, and what is the reason for doing it without punishment, for example. It will give us more context to answer from.

Comment: The "no punishment"  clause seems odd here. Do you really mean "no punishment" or maybe just "no physical punishment" a.k.a. no beating.

Comment: No physical punishment and how can u put a one year old in time out impossible but they are very smart and have understanding of what They're doing so I'm at my wits end so to say

Comment: "How do I put a 1 year old in time out?" Is a good question. Maybe you should ask it as a question.

Answer (score 1):

[LINK WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/parenting/guide/stop-children-from-biting#1)

[LINK](http://www.parenting.com/gallery/toddler-biting)

I liked what both these sites had to say. I'd try re-direction and a firm 'NO, we do not bite. It hurts." Then I would also try to make up a picture symbol board that allows your children to share how they are feeling. Cut simple pictures from magazines or copy images from the web. Post them in a prominent, reachable spot. Use the board to show your children how you feel, too. "I want lunch.", or, "I am sleepy." Separation for a few minutes is only slightly punitive, but perhaps they want a break from each other and can't tell you.

Sign language is something I recommend to all parents of infants because it takes the pressure off of having to use speech and gets the message across. There are only a few signs needed. I'd select, drink, food, sick, I want, finished/no more, more, sleep, help -- you choose.  [LINK Parenting](http://www.parenting.com/gallery/baby-sign-language-words-to-know)

This is perfectly normal and though not fun, children do grow out of it.

If you are concerned with time out [LINK: Dr. Sears](http://www.askdrsears.com/topics/parenting/discipline-behavior/10-time-out-techniques) Has some great ideas.

I've added some new links, if you have a specific concern, make that into a question and perhaps someone will have experienced something similar.

Disciplining toddlers:

[LINK - Parents](http://www.parents.com/toddlers-preschoolers/discipline/tips/7-tips-for-disciplining-your-toddler/)

[LINK - WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/parenting/guide/7-secrets-of-toddler-discipline#1)

[LINK - Parenting](http://www.parenting.com/article/8-discipline-mistakes-parents-make)

Answer (score 0):

Siblings fight. Twins do too. If twin1 bites twin2 and twin2 turns aroung and bites twin1 - then it stops, just ignore it. Twin2 is standing up for themselves (which is a good thing). Twin1 is learning that they can't push twin2 around (also a good thing). At 2 years old there is a limit to what they can do. 
 I'm not saying that it's ok for them to hurt other people. Obviously you need to teach them how to behave with others. Just understand that the relationship between the twins themselves will last their entire lives. Good or bad, they have to navigate the world together. Going to school, sharing friends, dating, summer camp... every part of their lives will see them side by side. They have to find a way to work it out. 
 I barely talk to my twin brother, but I think about him nearly every day. It doesn't seem to matter that we only see each other once in a blue moon.... he's still right next to me.